# solution to second order ode (not in standard form)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I used separation of variables to solve a linear PDE.

Thus, I arrived at the following ODES:

$$
u_{t} = - \lambda^{2} u = 0
$$

which has the solution:

$$ 
u = A \exp{(- \lambda^{2} t)}
$$
the 2nd ODE is given by:
$$ k u_{xx} + \frac{2k}{x} u_{x} + \lambda^{2} u = 0 $$
Here, $k, \lambda > 0$.
the boundary conditions to be applied to the 2nd ODE are:
$$u_{x} (0,t) = u(a,t) = 0$$

Just asking how do you solve the 2nd ODE and apply its B.Cs as the ODE is not a 2nd order ODE with constant coefficients.

After this, everything else seems quite easy.

Comment: Try the substitution $u(x) = v(x)/x$ ...

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $u(x) = v(x)/x$, the second order ODE becomes:
$$
k v_{xx} + \lambda^2 v = 0
$$

So the original ODE has the fundamental solution (for $k \lambda \neq 0$):
$$
u(x) = \frac{A \cos(\omega x) + B \sin(\omega x) }{x}, k \omega^2 = \lambda^2
$$

The function $u$ has the following expansion close to $x = 0$:
$$
u(x) = \frac{A}{x} + B\omega - \frac{A \omega^2}{2} x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)
$$

So, enforcing $u_x(0) = 0$ implies that $A = 0$ (otherwise we don't even have a derivative there). The second boundary condition requires:
$$
0 = B \frac{\sin(\omega a)}{a}
$$

So non-trivial solutions exist, when $\omega \in \frac{\pi}{a} \mathbb{N}$.

The case $\lambda = 0$ gives:
$$
u(x) = \frac{A + B x}{x}
$$

But this is impossible for the boundary conditions $u_x(0) = 0$ implies $A=0$ and then $u(a) = B$.

Summarizing, the general solution to your full PDE is then ($t \geq 0$):
$$
u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \frac{\sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{a} x \right)}{x} \exp\left( - k t \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{a^2} \right)
$$